# Airplane probability problem but a little different

Tags: probability

Some of you probably know the famous airbplane probability problem while discussing it in class the teacher gave us a different problem but similar:
Say there is an airplane with a 100 numbered sits
And there were 100 numbered passengers waiting in line.
Everyone but the first passenger have to go to take their designated seat unless it is taken in which case they take a random seat.
Now say the first passenger decided to take a random seat what’s the probability that the 100th passenger  sat in the first passenger seat(seat number 1)

Comment: You could start small. Start by considering only two seats. Then three. Then four ... What do you observe?

Comment: Also, first ask yourself the easier question, what's the probability that 100th passenger ends up in seat 2? in seat 3? Etc. (where "seat 2" means the seat held by 2nd person in line, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know from the classical airplane problem that the probability of the last person getting his own seat (i.e. seat 100) is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now suppose he finds his own seat occupied. Then someone is sitting in his seat with seat number $n_1 < n_0 := 100$. Either $n_1 = 1$, or that person got forced out of *their* seat - seat $n_1$ -  by someone with seat number $n_2 < n_1$, as noone picks a wrong seat voluntarily (*besides* passenger 1). This process goes on, up to the N-th iteration, where you find passenger 1: $n_N = 1$.

We have now identified all of the passengers who are misseated. None of them sits in seat $1$ (as they are sitting in seats $n_0, n_1, \ldots, n_{N - 1}$, the inequality $n_{i + 1} < n_i$ holds, and $n_N = 1$). Ergo seat $1$ is unoccupied, and passenger $100$ happily sits down in front of the plane.

We conclude that both the probability of getting his own seat and getting seat $1$ are $\frac{1}{2}$.